# Draw the following output as a Graph in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Below is the data I have in Microsoft Excel 2010

```
USER_ID    |    Actual_Count    |   Error_Count
-----------+--------------------+---------------------
1345653         5                     4
534140349       5                     0
682527813       4                     0
687612723       3                     0
704318001       5                     4
```

So if you look at the above scenario,

1. For this `1345653` USER_ID Out of `5`, it has `4` errors, same with `704318001` USER_ID, out of `5` it has `4` errors. And all other USER_ID's they didn't have any errors as `Error_Count` is `Zero` for them.
2. So I have total of `8` errors out of `22` tries, So an error percentage is about `36.36%`.

So my question is- How should I reflect the above two scenario as a graph in `Microsoft Excel 2010` so that when people look into those Graph in Excel 2010, they get the clear picture what is happening. Any help will be appreciated with step by step process what need to be done to make the graph.

**P.S I have no prior knowledge of working with Excel before.**

Comment: Just calculate these values and show them in a graph. I will make an example for you.

Comment: 1) What idea are you trying to communicate? (e.g. Certain users are the problem, or the error rate across the board is only 36%) 2) This *might* be a better question for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @tarheel, I want to communicate both of the above scenarios.

Comment: For future reference this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow (not programming). It is musch better suited to Super User

Answer (score 0):

I created an example for you. In it, I used your data and created some calculations of them. With these calculations, I created two graphs, one of columns (comparing the total count with the error count) and another comparing the percentage of errors with no errors. Take a look.

http://www.4shared.com/file/a739i8tQ/example.html

If you have any doubt relative that what I did, please comment. I'm using the brazilian portuguese version of excel, but I think that the function that I used (SOMA = SUM) will be "translated" to your version.

Try to change the data to see the graphs being updated.

Comment: Thanks david, Yes that will work for me. But can you explain me how you did that step by step so that I can also try the same thing in my excel 2010? it will be of great help to me.

Comment: Of course I can! The columns A, B and C contains your data. In column F, I used the SUM function, that is able to sum intervals. Select the cell "F2" and take a look at the function editor field (just above). It has this: =SUM(B2:B6) that means: perform a calculation (=) using the SUM function, using the interval B2 to (:) B6. The cell G2 is the same, but for the error count. In H2 I just subtracted the value of F2 in G2 (arithmetic operations may be used as in programming languages). I will continue with a new comment.

Comment: In the cells I2 and J2 I divide, respectively, the error count by the total and the no error count by the total and formatted these cells using the "percentage" format ("%" button at the "Number" section of the "Start Page" tab). I'm translating the names of the componentes of excel, so maybe I'm missing the correct names ok?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and what about the grpah?

Comment: For the graphs, first you go to the "Insert" tab, choose the type of the graph (The first one is columns) and the empty graph will be added. Next you need to select the data that you want to use in the graph. I will not explain step by step because I built the graphs testing the values that I selected until I have what I want. It's not difficult, you just need to explore the editor. Try to use the excel help too, it is very explicative.

Comment: For the first one, after creating the empty graph, i choose "Select Data" (I dont know if this is the correct name). This button is on the left of the graph layout. Clicking in it a dialog will appear. In the "Graph data interval" (again, i dont know if it is the correct name) you just need to click in the field and select the data in the spreadsheet. In this case (to start) the cells from F1 to G2, ad after that I started to edit the specific parts of the graph, like the labels, etc.